# Github copilot seems to be having problems

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-copilot

None of my extensions in VScode were working after disabling them all I see this message in the console.

[image]

Any idea how I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit belated, but in general I'd suggest updating both GitHub Copilot and VSCode to the latest versions if you appear to have compatibility problems.

In this particular case I suspect that you were using a newer version of Copilot with an old version of VSCode. We did try to set version restrictions to avoid this but they may not have worked properly.